# Vulnerability: cloud metadata potentially exposed

Tags: security, nginx, amazon-ec2

My website is hosted on EC2 (under Nginx in docker), I am using OWASP to scan vulnerabilities and I get the Alert `Cloud Metadata Potentially Exposed`  with `https://my-host/latest/meta-data/` 
I removed all of the $host in my nginx configure file and
I am using the DNS to forward the traffic in nginx configure file. My nginx config like that:

```
worker_processes 5;
error_log stderr info;

events {
    worker_connections 4096; # Default: 1024
}

http {
    log_format main
    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data:; frame-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; media-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; manifest-src 'none'; worker-src 'none'; prefetch-src 'none'; form-action 'none' " always;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    server_tokens off;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        access_log /dev/stdout main;

        # Forward to BE
        location /api {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_read_timeout 30s;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }

        # Forward Websocket
        location /ws/ {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 90s;
            proxy_pass http://backend/ws/;
        }

        # Default forward all to FE
        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_read_timeout 30s;
            proxy_pass http://frontend;
        }
        location /public/logs/ {
           alias /var/www/html/static_files/logs/;
           add_header Content-disposition "attachment";
        }

        location /public/ {
            alias /var/www/html/static_files/;
        }
    }

    upstream backend {
        server backend;
    }

    upstream frontend {
        server frontend;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion for me? Thanks all!